# Has there been any experiment showing that the velocity of light in solids changes in the presence of a magnetic field?

Tags: special-relativity, experimental-physics, speed-of-light

Has there been any experiment showing that velocity of light in solids changes in if magnetic field is introduced? We know that the polarization of light traveling through some solids may be altered by the presence of magnetic field but is there any experimental evidence that the velocity may be altered as well?

Comment: Have a careful  look at this wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_light

Comment: @anna v The wikipedia article which you are referring to doesn't mention influence of magnetic field alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Here's [a link to a paper](https://opg.optica.org/ome/fulltext.cfm?uri=ome-7-2-468&id=357362) demonstrating this in $\mathrm{La_{0.66}Sr_{0.33}MnO_3}$.

The effect may not be as pronounced in ordinary window glass, however.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the [Faraday effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect) is caused by the influence of the magnetic field on the velocity of circularly polarized light.